# Automatic deselect item of a slicer that does not belong to parent slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have two slicers in a dashboard, one for countries, and one for cities that belong to the selected country.

The problem is when I select Country A, Then City A-4 for example, then If I changed the country to B, I found the list of cities contains B-1, B-2, ... in addition to A-4 which belongs to country A, Not B!

I have to manually select another city from B-? hence, the A-4 city disappears from the cities list!

Is there a way to unselect any city from the cities slicer as soon as the country changed?

Comment: unable to understand, can you explain more or show image?

Comment: we have matrix visual that contains country and its productAnd we have two slicer both contains single select first is country that contains JJ,AS,DEand second is product ABC,ABC1,DEF,DEF1,JKL,JKL1. ABC,ABC1 Product belong to JJ,DEF,DEF1 belong to AS and JKL,JKL1BELONG TO DE.If we select country JJ it will show In product slicer ABC,ABC1and we want to see only ABC value so we select ABC value in slicer. However if we select AS so in the product slicer 3values is showing that isDEF,DEF1and3th value is ABC that is not belong to AS.if we select a DEF in Product slicer ABC is disappear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.